# How to post the nested dictionary as JSON body using swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
{
    "data": [{
        "_id": "1558946471217677c352281",
        "title": "ssds",
        "user_id": "",
        "user_name": "",
        "checklist": {
            "id": "5ccad234e47ab8565a45b6a2",
            "name": "task edited 2"
        },
        "idc": "5ccad234e47ab8565a45b6a2",
        "completed": 0,
        "created": "2019-05-27T22:41:11+14:00",
        "tps": 1,
        "tpe": 0
    }],
    "tz": "2d626e1289dafb70b0e890eb97bf5c4910b0a47edad9624b5973cdb244abe8fed5e6",
    "uID": "7c24d0c8c6034017556946c418bbf0b182ba6a0a62230a860c3319c8f137c06920da465df3d789d1"
}
```

Comment: what you tried and what is not working ?

Comment: Add your code to the question, it's very hard to read code posted in comments

Comment: With format, it's easier to read your JSON. But you also need to add your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare your dictionary format as follows:

```
let checklist = [
    "id": "5ccad234e47ab8565a45b6a2",
    "name": "task edited 2"
]



let data = [
        [
        "_id": "1558946471217677c352281",
        "title": "ssds",
        "user_id": "",
        "user_name": "",
        "checklist": "",
        "idc": "5ccad234e47ab8565a45b6a2",
        "completed": 0,
        "created": "2019-05-27T22:41:11+14:00",
        "tps": 1,
        "tpe": 0
        ],
        [
            "_id": "1558946471217677c352281",
            "title": "Abcd",
            "user_id": "",
            "user_name": "",
            "checklist": "",
            "idc": "5ccad234e47ab8565a45b6a2",
            "completed": 0,
            "created": "2019-05-27T22:41:11+15:00",
            "tps": 1,
            "tpe": 0
        ]
        ] as [[String : Any]]

let paramDict = [
    "data": [data],
    "tz":"2d626e1289dafb70b0e890eb97bf5c4910b0a47edad9624b5973cdb244abe8fed5e6",
    "uID":"7c24d0c8c6034017556946c418bbf0b182ba6a0a62230a860c3319c8f137c06920da465df3d789d1"
    ] as [String : Any]
```

Comment: @user3534730 Updated answer to add input data as an array